# Video cut does not match preview

Tags: edit-mode, video, audio

I have an iphone video (30 fps) with a person speaking a text. I am trying to cut it into single videos, each containing one sentence of the text. Therefore i use the blender video editor and set the start and end frames exactly where the sentence starts and ends (needs to be very precisely). That works perfectly in the blender editor.
However if i click on "Animation" and the file gets saved, then the resulting video file is shorter than in the preview in blender. Therefore i am missing the last part of a word in the sentence.

I post an image of my encoding settings.

Please help me

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When importing a video, you have to use the same frame rate. If you don't, the lenght of the video will change, but the audio will keep the same, resulting in a difference between audio and video.

25FPS video import with 25 FPS in render settings : audio and video have the same length
[image]

25FPS video import with 30 FPS in render settings : video is shorter (same number of frames but 5 more every second)
[image]

Comment: Thank for your answer, but that is not the solution to my problem, because it did that already right! The playback in blender is right. BUT blender does not save what it previews.